# Pull request for Joomla

Tags: discussion, joomla

Just though I'd mention that my request was accepted and will be put into Joomla 3.4.2 for JSE:

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/6868

Yay

Comment: That is just great!

Comment: Excellent work!

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Lodder :) Any rough estimates for when 3.4.2 will be released?

Comment: @moomoochoo - I'll ask and let you know in a bit

Comment: @moomoochoo - The reply I got: `I honestly don't know. We may just move to 3.5 at this point`

Comment: @Lodder OK, that's interesting. Thanks for asking :)